# ¿Porqué no se ejecuta mi aplicación?

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica, gradle, intellij-idea

Tengo un problema con IntelliJ, lo que pasa es que cada que ejecuto mi aplicación creada o la que se crea por defecto cuando inicias un nuevo proyecto no me aparece la ventana (Interfaz Grafica) y en la consola me aparece lo siguiente:

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0

You can use mode '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own script or plugins

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 9s
```

¿Qué puedo hacer para solucionarlo?

Comment: Tal vez te sirvan las respuestas en el foro de [jetbrains](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360004383639-How-to-add-Gradle-options)

Comment: Y en [respuestas de stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610420/deprecated-gradle-features-were-used-in-this-build-making-it-incompatible-with) recomiendan poner el flag `--warning-mode=all` para ver cuáles son exactamente los deprecated